# How to handle unsupported/unimplemented methods for Rest Client

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

so lets say, i am listening on URL `v1/shop/{PATH_PARAM}/status.xml`. Whenever, a request is made at `v1/shop/some_value/status.xml` It will be redirected to my method.

But lets say, a user does a mistake in this path ? Jersey would by itself send an response of "Bad Request" or "Un implemented" method or something like that. Is there a way that instead jersey sending this response, I can handle those reponse ? lets say i will create a new function which will listen ot *everything* except for those which i are implemented for business case. So any request, which is not properly structured, or some unsupported media request would go to this method, so that i can send a more resonable response to the user

Answer (score 0):

You could make a [Servlet Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html), configure it to intercept all URLs matching your Web Services root URL (or even the root URL of the web server where the web service is deployed), have it pass the request on to the web service and then when the response arrives at the filter, if it's some kind of web service error you can change the response to whatever you want, make it redirect to some custom error page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this using an "Exception Mapper".  Here is a tutorial on how to do it with resteasy:  https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RESTEasyExceptionHandlingWithExceptionMapper?_sscc=t

A colleague told me there is something analogous for Jersey.

Here is the code I used to make sure that I don't get empty content, because sometimes I forget, and I'm sure others will forget, to look at the headers / HTTP status.

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.Failure;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class PipelineMgrExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {


    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof Failure) {
            Failure f = (Failure) e;
            return Response.fromResponse(f.getResponse()).entity(f.getMessage()).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(500).entity(e.getMessage()).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
        }
    }
}
```